# How to list commands history with busybox?

Tags: busybox

I use busybox with buildroot on [apf51 board](http://www.opossom.com/english/products-processor_boards-apf51.html). In the console, I can recall a previously typed command with the "up arrow" or search in the command list with `Ctrl+g`.

But the command `history` doesn't exist:

```
# history
-sh: history: not found
```

Is there a way to list previously typed commands with busybox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since BusyBox is using ash, you should be able to read the history from the *~/.ash_history* file like:

```
$ tail ~/.ash_history
```